# Is this possible to link the value to a database in Apple's iWork suite?

Tags: data-synchronization, keynote, iwork, numbers

For example, I would like to make a Pages document that has a value that's linked to the company information and Keynotes and Numbers as well. So, when our company information changes, all the reference value can be changed. Is this possible to do? If not, does any office suite have this ability?

Comment: What exactly is the amount and contents of the company information? Example: Is is just the company address or hundreds of hundreds of rows of financial data?

Comment: address, phone number, fax number, etc.

Comment: There is no built-in function to do this as far as I know. You could try using AppleScript to script company info changes.

Answer (score 1):

In any program to find out what fields/data can be inserted at a given point look for the menu item "Insert" if there is one you will see under that menu diffent types of data that can be inserted.  I pages you can "Insert" any of the information from the Addressbook.  In numbers it is much more limited.

AppleScript is most probley to best solution for other data and the apps you ask about.

Better app's for this sort of thing are OpenOffice and MS-Office.

Answer (score 0):

The closest Pages offers is to merge data automatically from the address book or a Numbers document. See [Pages '09: Merging Data from Address Book or a Numbers Document](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10502)

One approach may be to edit the master template files and see if changes are retrospectively applied to existing documents.

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs has this functionality, though:

1. That's probably not an answer you wanted to hear
2. There isn't an already-made perfect solution for what you want to do

With Google Docs, all the functionality required is visible and there to be moulded, there are even online programming tools and hundreds of pages of documentation to go along with them.

Here's an example of work that may get you 80% of the way there:

[DocumentMerge](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/documentmerge-by-pandadoc/bfcfcgpdofganbehkmbdofgmifdgbmdn?hl=en) is an add-on for Google Docs that allows you to make a document that uses template-like codewords that are then replaced with data from a Google Spreadsheet.

You can then use [Zapier](http://zapier.com/) to connect any database to a Google spreadsheet.

If none of the currently available solutions fit, it's feasible to have a new add-on created that does exactly what you're looking for.